# How to extract tags from XML

Tags: php, xml

I have a simple XML extraction issue that should be solvable with straight PHP and not require any libraries.

All I need to do is extract the values of one tag. For example, given the string of XML:

```
<ResultSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ....>
 <Result>Foo</Result>
 <Result>Bar</Result>
</ResultSet>
```

I just need to put `Foo` and `Bar` in an array. What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: All three answers are correct and workable. I am selecting @jwhat only because his answer put the output to an array Thanks also to Pekka and Jeremy for additional solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = '<ResultSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Result>Foo</Result><Result>Bar</Result></ResultSet>';
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$result_array = array();
foreach ($obj->Result as $value) {
  $result_array[] = (string)$value;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There's [**simpleXML**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) in PHP 5 that should get you there quickly.

Check out the [**basic examples page**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score 2):

If PHP 5 you can use SimpleXML.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
foreach ($xml->ResultSet as $val)
{
  echo $val->Result.' ';
}
```